# Powershell - Array Loop for service start and copy files

Tags: powershell

I need help on a specific issue with Powershell.

What I am trying to do is that starting multiple services one bye one and after successfully start process, I need to copy some files from one location to another. These files are created only after the service/app is up. I need to check it from a string in a text file (like "Service successfully started").

I tried to make a for-each loop but because of copying and text check locations are different, I couldn't manage to do it. And honestly, I don't have much information about nested loops. Maybe you can give me some ideas to make this work.

For examples, for 1 service;

- Source folder file locations;

C:\sourcepath\location1\folder\abc.dat

C:\sourcepath\location1\folder\cde.dat

- txt file which needs to be checked if there is a string line called "Service successfully started" (to understand the service-app successfully started)

C:\sourcepath\folder1\logs\logfile.txt

- Destination folder file locations
  D:\destinationpath\location1\ (abc.dat and cde.dat files should be in same folder)

--- The flow should be like that;

- Start a service
- Make sure it's up as checking the txt file string
- After controls, make copying process from source folder to destination for the specified files (as creating destination folder based on source folder)
- Stop the service
- After checking it's status as stopped, again start another service and do the same processes until the last service but for different locations
  For example, location1 should be location2 and then location3 but the file names are the same. Also destination folder should be created according to source folder.

Even any directions will be helpful.

Edit1:

So far, I could write code.

```
[array]$serviceNames = "lfsvc", "iphlpsvc"
[array]$app = "app1", "app2"
$sourceStart = "C:\Source\"
$destinationStart = "C:\Target\"
$logs = "\logs"

$sourceFull = $sourceStart+$app.Get(0)+"\data"
$destinationFull = $destinationStart+$app.Get(0)

ForEach ($serviceNames in $serviceNames) 
{
    Start-Service $serviceNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    $text = Select-String -Path $sourceStart+$app.Get(0)+$logs\log.txt -Pattern "Service successfully started"
    if ($text -ne $null)
    { 
        md $destination;
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFull\123.txt -Destination $destinationFull\123.txt
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFull\456.txt -Destination $destinationFull\456.txt
    }
}
```

- I need to point other $app values in a row as pointing other $serviceNames values accordingly.
- I need to take control the if values if wait till it shows the service successfully started line

Thanks

Edit2:
If I want to write it in long way, that should be something like that. (Ofc, if I can check the string from a specified text file, it would be gr8)

I need to shorten the codes

```
[array]$serviceNames = "aService", "bService"

Start-Service $serviceNames[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Start-Sleep -Seconds 75;
md "C:\Dest\aService\fld";
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\aService\fld\123.txt" -Destination "C:\Dest\aService\fld\123.txt";
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\aService\fld\456.txt" -Destination "C:\Dest\aService\fld\456.txt";
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\aService\fld\789.txt" -Destination "C:\Dest\aService\fld\789.txt";
Stop-Service $serviceNames[0] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15;

Start-Service $serviceNames[1] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Start-Sleep -Seconds 75;
md "C:\Dest\bService\fld";
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\bService\fld\123.txt" -Destination "C:\Dest\bService\fld\123.txt";
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\bService\fld\456.txt" -Destination "C:\Dest\bService\fld\456.txt";
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\bService\fld\789.txt" -Destination "C:\Dest\bService\fld\789.txt";
Stop-Service $serviceNames[1] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15;
```

Comment: Where's the error in your current code?

Comment: I don't know how to make nested loop or the logic behind which I should do so, I cannot give you some error for it. If I can't find some lead here, I will write the codes line by line without putting them in loops.

Comment: I'd start with the controller script. Getting the content from your files as variables and looping through them. One loop with all those steps you listed as lines inside the loop should work.

Comment: Once you have some specific issue rather than general design, I'd open up a new question asking for details on a specific error message/missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea of what you want.

```
[array]$serviceNames = "lfsvc", "iphlpsvc"
[array]$apps = "app1", "app2"
$sourceStart = "C:\Source\"
$destinationStart = "C:\Target\"
$logs = "\logs"

# main loop, which loops over the apps

foreach($app in $apps)
{
    $sourceFull = $sourceStart + $app + "\data"
    $destinationFull = $destinationStart + $app
    # each app will iterate over all of the services
    ForEach ($name in $serviceNames) 
    {
        # uses -passthru to get the service object, and pulls its status from that. Will cause any errors to terminate the script
        $status = (Start-Service $name -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru).Status

        # this while loop will cause it to pause until the service is in "running" state
        while($status -ne "Running") {Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; Get-Service $name}
        $text = Select-String -Path $($sourceStart + $app + $logs + "\log.txt") -Pattern "Service successfully started"

        # check to see if the $text variable is null or empty, if not, do the thing
        if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($text))
        { 
            if(!(Test-Path -Path $destinationFull)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationFull}
            Get-Content -Path "$sourceFull\123.txt" | Add-Content -Path "$destinationFull\123.txt"
            Get-Content -Path "$sourceFull\456.txt" | Add-Content -Path "$destinationFull\456.txt"
       
        }

        # stops the service
        $status = Stop-Service $name -PassThru

        # pauses until the service is stopped
        while($status -ne "Stopped") {Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; Get-Service $name}
    }
}
```

something like this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each app should not iterate over all the services because they have specific locations. For example, app1 and its path location is bound to only "lfsvc", and app2 is bound to only iphlpsvc service. It should go on like that. And hate to say that I have to write the code line by line with start-sleep. code's quality pretty bad but can send you an example for it to let you understand better.